# Wrong Grocery Items when I add Items to the cart

Tags: java, bluej

This is for my class assignment. I keep getting the wrong groceryitem in the output. How should I go about getting the right item when the code is ran?

Here is the output i am currently getting:

Shopper Name: Gary

---

ice cream:5 units at $4.25 per unit = $21.25

ice cream:5 units at $4.25 per unit = $21.25

----> Subtotal = $42.5

----> 7% tax = $2.975

---->Total = $45.475

Shopper Name: Sally

---

ice cream:2 units at $4.25 per unit = $8.5

ice cream:2 units at $4.25 per unit = $8.5

----> Subtotal = $17.0

----> 7% tax = $1.1900000000000002

---->Total = $18.19

---

Cart Class:

```
public class Cart
{
public String Name;
public int ItemNum;
public double tax;




public Cart(String ShopperName){
    Name = ShopperName;
}
public String getShopperName(){
    return Name;
}
public int getItemNumber(){
    return ItemNum;
}
public void addItem1(GroceryItem GroceryItem, int NumberItem){
    GroceryItem = GroceryItem;
    ItemNum = NumberItem;
}
public void addItem2(GroceryItem GroceryItem, int NumberItem){
    GroceryItem = GroceryItem;
    ItemNum = NumberItem;
}
public double getItemTotal(){
    double item_total = (double) (GroceryItem.getCost()*getItemNumber());
    return item_total;
}
public double getSubtotal(){
    double subtotal = (double) (getItemTotal() + getItemTotal());
    return subtotal;
}
public double getTaxTotal(){
    double tax = .07;
    double taxtotal = (double) (getSubtotal()*tax);
    return taxtotal;
}
public double getTotal(){
    double Total = (double) (getTaxTotal()+getSubtotal());
    return Total;
}
public void printReceipt(){
    System.out.println("Shopper Name: " + getShopperName());
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(GroceryItem.getName()+":"+ getItemNumber()+ " units at $" + GroceryItem.getCost()+" per unit"+ " = $"+ getItemTotal());
    System.out.println(GroceryItem.getName()+":"+ getItemNumber()+ " units at $" + GroceryItem.getCost()+" per unit"+ " = $"+ getItemTotal());
    System.out.println("----> Subtotal = $" + getSubtotal());
    System.out.println("----> 7% tax = $" + getTaxTotal() );
    System.out.println("---->Total = $" + getTotal());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Driver Class:

```
/**
 * Driver for Cart and GroceryItem.
 */
public class Driver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create grocery items
    GroceryItem item1 = new GroceryItem("milk", 3.39);
    GroceryItem item2 = new GroceryItem("eggs", 1.75);
    GroceryItem item3 = new GroceryItem("ice cream", 4.25);

    // create new carts
    Cart shopper1 = new Cart("Gary");
    Cart shopper2 = new Cart("Sally");


    // add items to first cart 
    shopper1.addItem1(item2, 1);        //1 "eggs" is being added
    shopper1.addItem2(item1, 5);        //5 "milk" are being added

    // add items to second cart
    shopper2.addItem1(item3, 2);        //2 "ice cream" are being added
    shopper2.addItem2(item2, 2);        //2 "eggs" are being added

    // print cart's receipt
    shopper1.printReceipt();
    shopper2.printReceipt(); 

}
}
```

Comment: `GroceryItem = GroceryItem;` The definition of the GroceryItem field is missing. But it seems you're overwriting it all the time.

Comment: Also, think about how long you want to program on this. I want to buy 934 items. So you want to implement 934 addItemXXX() methods?

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
public void addItem1(GroceryItem GroceryItem, int NumberItem){
    GroceryItem = GroceryItem;
    ItemNum = NumberItem;
}
```

you're assigning GroceryItem to itself.

Same for the addItem2 method.

Actually, your cart does not seem to have any way to store the items. It looks like you're not grasping the essentials here. Back to the books I'm afraid....

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the items to itself in your `addItem` methods. Declare instances variables and specify you're assigning to instance variable by using `this`.

For example:

```
public class Cart {
private GroceryItem groceryItem;
...

public void addItem1(GroceryItem groceryItem, int NumberItem){
    this.groceryItem = groceryItem;
    ...
```

Then when you print the result, use the instance variable `groceryItem`.

Also, in `java`, members (variable/method names) should be in [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java).

Comment: cannot find symbol - variable GroceryItem

Comment: I've updated the answer with instance variable declaration but I recommend you to read more on Java. Official Java tutorials is a good place to start.

Comment: This example cart only has space for one item, adding a new item will replace any current item.